# Inconsistent download size with PHP + NGINX configuration

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, php-fpm, php5

I'm building a Joomla website using docman for document management/downloading. The site is built on a Ubuntu 14.04 server running Nginx 1.4.2 and PHP5 (FPM).

The issue i'm having is that files are downloading inconsistently (in terms of size). For example, I downloaded a PDF file 6 times from the website with the following results:

- 72KB
- 75KB
- 146KB
- 177KB (complete file)
- 72KB
- 177KB (complete file)

for this test, the full file downloaded correctly 2 out of 6 times. The other 4 times the file was incomplete.

My nginx.conf looks like this

```
user       www-data;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
        worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
        include    /etc/nginx/conf/mime.types;
        include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        include    /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        index    index.php app.php index.html index.htm;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
        '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
        access_log   logs/access.log  main;
        sendfile     on;
        tcp_nopush   on;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts

        keepalive_timeout 0;

        #GZIP#
        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 4 8k;
        gzip_types text/plain application/xhtml+xml text/css application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
        gzip_proxied     any;
        gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

The site configuration looks like the following:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

        root /www/sites/canmore.link/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
        # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        # deny running scripts inside writable directories
        location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
                return 403;
                error_page 403 /403_error.html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }


        # caching of files
        location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
                expires 1y;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
                expires 14d;
        }

}
```

Here is the logfile http://pastebin.com/br0u36xp

```
2015/11/15 23:51:06 [info] 16075#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 24.64.69.223, server: canmore.link, request: "$
2015/11/15 23:51:07 [crit] 16075#0: *3 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/1/00/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 24.64.69.223, $
2015/11/16 00:24:09 [info] 16228#0: *68 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 24.64.69.223, server: canmore.link, request: $
2015/11/16 00:24:10 [crit] 16228#0: *70 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/1/00/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 24.64.69.223,$
2015/11/16 00:31:46 [info] 16262#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 24.64.69.223, server: canmore.link, request: "$
2015/11/16 00:31:53 [crit] 16262#0: *5 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/1/00/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 24.64.69.223, $
2015/11/16 00:38:24 [error] 16318#0: *4 open() "/www/sites/canmore.link/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 24.64.69.223, server: canmo$
2015/11/16 00:38:24 [info] 16318#0: *1 client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream, client: 24.64.6$
2015/11/16 00:38:51 [info] 16318#0: *17 client 24.64.69.223 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2015/11/16 00:38:52 [crit] 16318#0: *14 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/3/00/0000000003" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 24.64.69.223,$
2015/11/16 00:38:55 [crit] 16318#0: *13 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/4/00/0000000004" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 24.64.69.223,$
2015/11/16 00:39:23 [info] 16360#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 24.64.69.223, server: canmore.link, request: "$
2015/11/16 00:39:23 [crit] 16360#0: *3 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/1/00/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 24.64.69.223, $
2015/11/16 00:40:33 [info] 16388#0: *44 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 24.64.69.223, server: canmore.link, request: $
2015/11/16 00:40:34 [crit] 16388#0: *46 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/1/00/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 24.64.69.223,$
2015/11/16 00:40:44 [crit] 16388#0: *48 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/2/00/0000000002" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 24.64.69.223,$
```

Comment: What does your web server error log say for the failed downloads?

Comment: Here's the log file from the last few attempts http://pastebin.com/br0u36xp @EEAA

Comment: Please edit your question and include relevant lines there.

Comment: First fix the easy permission problem. If it doesn't clear up then, you can move on.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - logfile was telling... was as simple as changing permissions on the /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi folder to allow www-data to own it. FML, that took forever for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved based on logfile...

I changed permissions on the /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi folder and it worked.

```
chown -R www-data /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi
```